# Create sample flutter plugin to import AndroidX and get error cannot resolve symbol 'XXX'

Tags: flutter

I have created a sample flutter plugin and follow the AndroidX compatibility document to upgrade plugin to AndroidX 
1. Edit Android Code in Android Studio 
2. Use IDE Migrating to AndroidX 
3. classpath is still 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0', manually change to 3.3.0 
4. gradle.properties has

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

appended by IDE 
5.

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

has changed by IDE 
6.

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

has changed by IDE 
7. after that I add a Java class "ImagePickerFileProvider" copied from Image Picker Plugin, but still get error "Cannot resolve symbol 'FileProvider'"

```
package xxx.flutter_plugin_androidx_test;

import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

/**
 * Providing a custom {@code FileProvider} prevents manifest {@code <provider>} name collisions.
 *
 * <p>See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html for details.
 */
public class ImagePickerFileProvider extends FileProvider {}
```

Comment: only `"Cannot resolve symbol"`? without the name of that "symbol"?

Comment: add Cannot resolve symbol 'FileProvider' in this case. Thanks.

Comment: androidx.core.content.FileProvider , I copy this class from image picker plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I create an Android project and compare build.gradle (Module: app) and append the following line to dependencies

   ```
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
       implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
       implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
   ```

   The snippet

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
       implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
       implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
   }
   ```
2. Compared build.gradle(Module: your_project_name) with flutter plugin and append

   ```
   dependencies {
       api 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
   }
   ```

   the snippet

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 28

       defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 21
         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       lintOptions {
         disable 'InvalidPackage'
       }
     }

   dependencies {
       api 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
   }
   ```
3. rebuild project and reopen project